# Adding numbers in several arrays together with ruby

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby, rubygems, mysql2

I am using the ruby mysql2 gem to work with a database. I want to list all the countries per region in one table, then add up the hits per region.

Normally I would use the mysql `SUM` function, but the gem returns the headers so this is not possible.

Instead, I am getting the hit count for each country per region and add it up.
The gem returns 1 array per result and I need to get that result and add it to a running total per region.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
# simple.rb - simple MySQL script using Ruby MySQL module

require "rubygems"
require "mysql2"

client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root", :database => "cbscdn")
regions = client.query("select Id from Regions")

regions.each(:as => :array) do |rid|
  hit = client.query("select hits from Countries where Regions_Id='#{rid}'")
  hit.each(:as => :array) do |a|
    a.map do |x|
      x.to_i
    end
  end
end
```

How can I implement the running count per region?

Comment: I had to turn each result that was each an array into a fixnum, add it to a new array, then add all the values in the array to get the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for any reason you don't want to delegate it to the database engine, you can do this way:
(for simplicity, I assume your results are already arrays)

```
regions_count = regions.inject({}) do |hash, rid|
  hit = client.query("whatever")
  hash[rid] = hit.map(&:to_i).inject(0, :+)
  hash
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Let the database do the work:

```
client.query(%q{
    select regions_id, sum(hits)
    from countries
    group by regions_id
}).each(:as => :array) do |row|
    region_id, total_hits = row
    #...
end
```

And if you want sums for regions that aren't in the `countries` table:

```
client.query(%q{
    select r.id, coalesce(sum(c.hits), 0)
    from regions r
    left outer join countries c
    on r.id = c.regions_id
    group by r.id
}).each(:as => :array) do |row|
    region_id, total_hits = row
    #...
end
```

Comment: "Normally I would use the mysql SUM function, but the gem returns the headers so this is not possible."
The mysql function returns the headers as i was using the cli as well as the total. so the results are invalid.

Comment: @willejs: I don't understand what that means or what the MySQL CLI has to do with this.

Comment: If i use the mysql2 gem and do that query, i receive the result, but complete with headers and formatting into an array, scrambling the results making them unreadable.

Comment: @willejs: I get nice row hashes out of `client.query(...).each { |h| ... }` or nice simple row arrays out of `client.query(...).each(:as => :array) { |row| ... }` so I don't understand where your problem is.